# CABasicAnimation not having any effect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I'm having a very simple issue, and I'm pulling out my hair over it. I'm trying to animate the moving of an NSButton. Now, I am aware of the almost overly simple:

```
[[button animator] setFrame:newCGRect];
```

However, I'd like to increase the time it takes for the button to travel. So, I looked into the slightly more complex CABasicAnimation. I *think* I'm doing everything correctly, but the NSButton isn't moving at all.

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(10, 20);

CALayer *layer = button.layer;

layer.position = CGPointMake(button.frame.size.width / 2, button.frame.size.height / 2);

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithPoint:center]];
[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setDuration:3.0];

[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Here, button is the NSButton. I'm setting the position of layer to the center of the button, because I *think* that "position" has to refer to the center. Then, all I'm doing is moving (supposedly) the button to center, in an animation that is 3 seconds long. I add the animation to the layer, and then, nothing happens.

Now, does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Or, on a side note, is there anyway to use the animator property *and* set the length of the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my original code was overkill, and Jason Harwig's answer below was more accurate. The only problem was his did not animate with the given duration when animating an NSView subclass (in this case, an NSButton). To remedy to this, here is the following code, that animates with the given duration:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:8];
[[button animator] setFrame:newRect];  
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Comment: So, if this solves your issue it's not only okay but even desired that you accept your own answer so people can easily see the correct answer at first glance. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I would be glad to accept it, but considering I have less than 100 reputation points, I have to wait two days (by now, one day) to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the implicit animation in a transaction to adjust the animation.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:3];
[[button animator] setFrame:newframe];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I've figured out the answer. For reference, your answer is slightly off, as it does animate, but does not respect the given duration. This is because when using CATransaction, you can only modify a CALayer, not an NSView subclass. See my answer for further details.